# How to add custom attributes in wordpress TinyMce

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm developing a plugin to insert some form like

How can I insert within TinyMce editor using the `ed.insertContent()` function? I have searched many solutions but none worked

Here is my code...

```js
onsubmit: function( e ) {
ed.insertContent("<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script> ");
ed.insertContent("<script src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js'></script> ");
ed.insertContent("<script src='https://api.infiniforms.io/scripts/infiniforms.js'></script> ");
ed.insertContent("<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'></script> ");

ed.insertContent("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' /> ");


ed.insertContent("<x-infiniforms client='7759c01e-f353-4eb6-ab1a-6f7e6ca37cc7'    form='58904c95-1f94-45d8-a172-bff7a2064d78' />");
},
```

Comment: So what happens when your code runs? What errors do you get? Without more details it will be hard for someone to help you.

Comment: I don't think you need to add JQuery, as it is included in WordPress.